# grammar of アンタに用事がある

Tags: grammar

> アンタに少し用事があるからこの後付き合いなさい

in context it is one person asking another to go somewhere with them.

but with アンタに用事がある alone, what is it really saying?

用事 exists in you?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アンタに用事がある (or 用がある) alone means something like "I need to speak to you". That is, not アンタ but the speaker has the 用事. I think this に is a direction/target marker rather than a location marker used with ある/いる.

Similar examples:

- 君に話がある。 I have something to talk with you.
- 彼に電話がありました。 There was a call asking for him.
- お前には貸しがある。 You owe me one. (lit. "I have a lending about you")
- お前には借りがある。 I owe you one. (lit. "I have a borrowing about you")

Comment: would ___に貸しがあってね apply as well? (he owes a debt to me?)

Comment: @xyz That's a good example, I added to the list.

Comment: would this more abstract concept also apply? Or it it more the relationship doesn't exist between the two ? ツンデレと呼び捨てに因果関係はありませんよね

Comment: @xyz In that ツンデレ example, に is simply an abstract location marker. "There is no cause-result relationship *in/between* tsundere and yobisute, right?".